# Python Script for Zonal Statistics As Table results empty Table

Tags: python, arcmap, zonal-statistics, statistics

I have a TIFF format file and want to automate some tasks. I have a Python script for Zonal Statistics as Table but it results in empty table output. However, the Zonal Statistics As Table Tool at ArcMap runs successfully! What is the problem with the Script?

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')

arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/Data/Hydro/"

raster_list = arcpy.ListRasters("*.tif")
lisTable = arcpy.ListTables()

zone = "D:/Data/Catch.shp"

# Loop through each file and perform the zonal statistics processing
for raster in raster_list:
    raster_name = os.path.basename(raster).rstrip(os.path.splitext(raster)[1])
    outTable = raster_name + ".dbf"
    arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable(zone, "NAME", raster, outTable, "NODATA", "MEAN_STD")
```

[image]

Comment: I recreated your script using my own data and it worked fine for me. Maybe double check that the input data matches what you used when running the Tool in ArcMap? I could not reproduce your error of the blank table either.

Comment: Thanks @JamiRae  The inputs for the ArcMap and the python script are the same. The same script works for me for other similar TIFF files and not for these files. I am not clear why! I even changed the working directory, however the result is the same; empty table!

Comment: @ JamiRae You can find a subset of the original TIFF file for your reference here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i4TlS4ycuIsVp4UxBqjmoWTVs1ZnIiz6

Answer (score 2):

The script worked fine when I removed the "NODATA" value I was passing to the [ignore_nodata](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm#GUID-D6D8972E-1851-4C3F-A9D5-1E87145988DB) parameter and simply put the double quotation instead.  This switches the functionality from ignoring all zones that contain NODATA values to the default behavior of excluding NODATA values from the calculations of a zone's statistics and not skipping zones that contain NODATA values.

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')

arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/Data/Hydro/"

raster_list = arcpy.ListRasters("*.tif")
lisTable = arcpy.ListTables()

zone = "D:/Data/Catch.shp"

# Loop through each file and perform the zonal statistics processing
for raster in raster_list:
    raster_name = os.path.basename(raster).rstrip(os.path.splitext(raster)[1])
    outTable = raster_name + ".dbf"
    arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable(zone, "NAME", raster, outTable, "", "MEAN_STD")
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your files and it worked just fine. Pretty sure your issue is that your files are ADF (Esri Grid files, not a TIF) so simply change this line

```
raster_list = arcpy.ListRasters("*.tif")
```

to this

```
raster_list = arcpy.ListRasters("*")
```

And it should work. I had no problem with it working.

Comment: I checked it again, no output! I tried to build an attribute table using Copy Raster Tool and run the script and still no output in the dbf.

Comment: @Daniel - that is strange! I just ran it again and it works fine for me. Here's the script I used:
http://gisdiva.com/downloads/stackx/Zonal/


![screenshot](http://gisdiva.com/downloads/stackx/Zonal/PyZonalOutput.png)